# When you're going to be late for a meeting

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Let's assume that you are going to be late for a meeting. 
I wonder when do you normally use each sentence below?

> **1)** I’m sorry **for keeping you / to keep you** waiting.

- I would use this sentence both before seeing the person who is waiting me e.g. through a phone call while I'm in the taxi and called them and using this sentence as an apology.

> **2)** I am sorry **to have kept you** waiting.

- I think it can be used only when you reach the person who you have kept him waiting on the meeting and you'e going to apologize him in this way.

I wonder what do you think?

Comment: I'm sorry to keep you waiting would mean that they are still waiting, as it is present tense. However, the other two are fine.

Comment: Thank you @Bee. I know they are fine, but please tell me when they can be used? Thinking twice about them, I think I can use them both when **still they are waiting** and when **I have already arrived to them** and we are talking face to face". Right?

Comment: All three can be used if they are still waiting, however, "to keep you" is the only one to explicitly implies they are still waiting. The other two can be used if you have just arrived